# Is deduction of multiple template arguments in an explicit specialization of a function template allowed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-specialization, template-argument-deduction, function-templates

The following quote from [[temp.expl.spec.11]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#11):

> **A trailing *template-argument*** can be left unspecified in the *template-id* naming an explicit function template specialization provided **it** can be deduced from the function argument type.

indicates that only a **single** trailing template argument may be deduced. Which would make the following exemplary code incorrect:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void f(T1, T2*);  

template<>
void f(int, double*) { }

int main()
{
    auto d = 2.0;
    f(1, &d);
}
```

However, the code compiles fine with GCC and Clang. Do these compilers apply some non-standard language extension, or is the deduction supported for **multiple trailing arguments**?

If the latter is true, why the sentence is not formed as follows?

> **Trailing *template-arguments*** can be left unspecified in the *template-id* naming an explicit function template specialization provided **they** can be deduced from the function argument type**s**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "a" at the start refers to *any* not to *one*.

> A[ny] trailing *template-argument* can be left unspecified in the *template-id* naming an explicit function template specialization provided it can be deduced from the function argument type.

Here's a sentence that I just made up:

> A function parameter's type *T* is adjusted to *const T* before prior analysis.

This doesn't mean that only one of the many parameters is adjusted, but every one of them; if any, since it could also be that there are no parameters.

The "a" refers in a more general sense to any one thing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am not a native speaker and these subtleties sometimes still make problems to me.

Comment: @DanielLangr oh yeah me too, I know the feeling - it sucks :(

Answer (score 3):

The quote does not indicate only a single parameter can be left off.

> A trailing template-argument can be left unspecified in the template-id naming an explicit function template specialization provided it can be deduced from the function argument type.

Means that a(any) parameter is allowed to be left off if it can be deduced.  So in

```
template<>
void f(int, double*) { }
```

We don't need to specifiy `T1` because it can be deduced from `int`, and we don't need to specify `T2` because it can be deducedfrom `double*`.

If the standard only allowed a single parameter to not  be specified it would word it like

> A single trailing template-argument can be left unspecified in the template-id naming an explicit function template specialization provided it can be deduced from the function argument type.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am not a native speaker and these subtleties sometimes still make problems to me.

Comment: @DanielLangr No worries.  I'm a native speaker and it still gives me trouble from time to time.  English is wacky.